# Dynamic change in input to a tensor at run time in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, dynamic

Is it possible to change the input to a tensor dynamically during run time in tensorflow based on a flag which is a placeholder?

Eg:

```
check = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='check')

if <`check` condition == `True`>:
    output = node_1
else:
    output = node_2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the TensorFlow [control flow operations](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/control_flow_ops#Control_Flow_Operations) like [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond). For example:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
check = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='check')
output = tf.cond(check, lambda: tf.add(x, 2), lambda: tf.add(x, 3))

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(output, feed_dict={check:True, x:3}))
  print(sess.run(output, feed_dict={check:False, x:3}))
```

will print:

5 (3+2 when check is True), and 6 (3+3 when check is False)
Hope that helps.